# Run a shell command from Django

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm developing a web page in Django (using apache server) that needs to call a shell command to enable/dissable some daemons. I'm try to do it with

`os.system(service httpd restart 1>$HOME/out 2>$HOME/error)`

and this command doesn't return anything. Any idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 10):

I'll skip the part where I strongly advise you about the implications of having a web application starting and stopping system processes and try to answer the question.

Your django application shouldn't run with *root* user, which should probably be needed to start and stop services. You can probably overcome this by:

- creating a script that uses [seteuid](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)
- give that file the set uid attribute

The script would be something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python <- or wherever your python interpreter is
import os
os.seteuid(0)
os.system("service httpd restart 1>$HOME/out 2>$HOME/error")
```

To allow setting the effective UID to root (0), you have to run, in a shell, as root:

```
chown root yourscript.py
chmod u+s yourscript.py
chmod a+x yourscript.py
```

That should do it. In your Django app you can now call `os.system('yourscript.py')` to run the command with root permissions.

Finally, I believe that the command you're passing to `os.system()` isn't what you're looking for, since you talk about enabling and disabling daemons and all you're doing is restarting apache... which in turn seems to be where your django is running, so in practice you'll be killing your own webapp.

Comment: This will not work for most users because the seteuid operation wont be permitted in script for security reasons. If it did work anybody could do "python -c 'import os; os.setuid(0);os.setgid(0);os.system("sh")'" to get themselves a root shell!

Answer (score 4):

Try run the command in Shell:

```
import subprocess
r = subprocess.call("service httpd restart 1>$HOME/out 2>$HOME/error", shell=True)
```

Comment: the correct spelling of the parameter is "shell", not "Shell".

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I use for launching process from my one of my django app:

```
  import subprocess
  process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'some_command'])
```

In your case it would be:

```
import subprocess     
process = subprocess.Popen(['service', 'httpd', 'restart'])
```

(also you need to handle stdout and stderr - not sure if adding '1>$HOME/out') would work with Popen. There is [documentation for subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Why would you use `subprocess` instead of the built-in Django `call_command` method for running your `./manage.py some_command`? See the full suggested solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40063425/1224827

Comment: @Blairg23: My manage.py is renamed to something else. Can we still call call_command?

Comment: @kta You should be able to use `./<whatever_you_named_it_to>.py some_command`, have you tried it? The documentation simply says `call_command` should call management commands, it doesn't imply any naming convention. That being said, it's not generally recommended to rename core system files, as it requires a bit of refactoring of internal stuffings.