# How to execute ksh script present on my linux box from a button present on web browser page

Tags: linux, django, django-models, websocket, unix-socket

I have a small task which i want to give a GUI look and feel.
There are many shell scripts (`.sh` & `.ksh`) present in my Linux machine, I want to execute them from Webpage.

Eg: `/user/###/##/diff.ksh` present on my linux box. i want to execute it from Browser. Webpage is made using `Django` framework.

Please let me with the connection setting between Linux and Browser.

Comment: A couple questions off the top of my head ... 1) Are you running your web browser from/on the same linux box where the scripts reside, or could your browser session be run from any machine that has network access to your linux box?  2) What happens if/when one of those shell scripts generates output ... are you planning on capturing and displaying that output in your browser? I'm thinking you've either left out a lot of details or ... possibly ... need to put a bit more thought into what it is you're trying to accomplish ... ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a shell command from Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037068/run-a-shell-command-from-django)